# Calculate the percentage of empty attributes in an object list

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object list like that :

```
var lstOcc = new List<Objet>();
...

public class Objet 
{
  public List<crit> lstcrit { get; set; }
}

public class crit 
{
  public string ValeurCrit { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to calculate for each crit the percentage of empty crit and make a list whith these values.

If my object has 20 crit, I would like a list with 20 percentages. This line of code count empty crit and make a list.

I know i could make a foreach but I want to improve my level in c# and linq.

I try to divide each value with the number of crit and I don't know if it's possible.

```
List<float> lstTemp = lstOcc.Select(occ => occ.Criteres.Select(crit => crit.ValeurCrit.Equals("")).Count() / lstOcc.Count).ToList();
```

the ToList return a list of occ and not crit and if I want a List it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

ex :

```
occ1 crit[0].val = "toto" crit[1].val = ""
occ2 crit[0].val = "toto" crit[1].val = "toto"
occ3 crit[0].val = "" crit[1].val = ""

crit[0] is filled at 66 %
crit[1] is filled at 33 %

So I want a List<float> like that :
lst[0] = 66.66
lst[1] = 33.33
```

Is it clear ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Please reformulate this : "I would like to calculate for each crit the percentage of empty crit and make a list whith these values." so I can help.

Comment: Yes, it's a little bit difficult to explain.

Comment: Your example makes no sense, and the names used do not match. Since you say you know how to do it in a loop, please post a small example that can actually be compiled; from there it should be much easier to see what you want, and help you convert it to LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is pivot the `lstcrit` in each `Objet` so you can count the empty and total elements. You can use `Enumerable.Range` for this:

```
var ans = Enumerable.Range(0, lstOcc.First().lstcrit.Count)
                    .Select(n => lstOcc.Select(o => o.lstcrit[n]))
                    .Select(critseq => critseq.Count(c => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.val)) / (double)critseq.Count());
```

Comment: `c.val` should be replaced with `c.ValeurCrit`...otherwise, great answer..However, the result should contain the count for the second `lstOcc` as well

Comment: @gkb I went with the `.val` from the example provided because it was shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I Guess this is what you are looking for -

```
var crit1 = new crit { ValeurCrit = "string 1" };
var crit2 = new crit { ValeurCrit = "" };
var crit3 = new crit { ValeurCrit = "string 2" };
var crit4 = new crit { ValeurCrit = "" };

var crit5 = new crit { ValeurCrit = "string 3" };
var crit6 = new crit { ValeurCrit = "" };
var crit7 = new crit { ValeurCrit = "" };
var crit8 = new crit { ValeurCrit = "" };
var crit9 = new crit { ValeurCrit = "" };
var crit10 = new crit { ValeurCrit = "string 4" };

var o1 = new Objet 
{
    lstcrit = new List<crit>() {crit1, crit2, crit3, crit4}
};
var o2 = new Objet 
{
    lstcrit = new List<crit>() {crit5, crit6, crit7, crit8, crit9, crit10}
};

var lstOcc = new List<Objet>() { o1, o2 };

var result = lstOcc.Select(x => x.lstcrit.Where(y => string.IsNullOrEmpty(y.ValeurCrit)).Select(a => a).Count() * 100.00m / (decimal)x.lstcrit.Count()).ToList();

//Result
//50.00
//66.6666..
```

This computes the percent of Empty strings in the list.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just noticed you beat me

Comment: Thanks, It's almost that... I want a list of crit and not a list of occ. iy my object has 10 crit, i want a list with 10 values. In fact i will use this list to make a chart

Comment: As per your question, it seems you are interested in `crit`s within `occ`s with empty `ValeurCrit`s.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: @gkb answered first with a more or less similar answer.

I think this is what you're looking for?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var lstOcc = new List<Objet>{
            new Objet
            {
                lstcrit = new List<crit>
                {
                    new crit{ValeurCrit = "one"}, 
                    new crit{ValeurCrit = "two"}, 
                    new crit{ValeurCrit = ""}, 
                    new crit{ValeurCrit = "three"}, 
                    new crit{ValeurCrit = ""}
                }
            }, 
            new Objet{
                lstcrit = new List<crit>
                {
                    new crit{ValeurCrit = ""}, 
                        new crit{ValeurCrit = ""}, 
                        new crit{ValeurCrit = ""}, 
                        new crit{ValeurCrit = "two"}, 
                        new crit{ValeurCrit = "four"}}}};
        var res = lstOcc.Select(o => (double)o.lstcrit.Where(c => c.ValeurCrit.Equals("")).Count() / (double)o.lstcrit.Count());
        res.ToList().ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine((100*r).ToString("0.00") + "%"));       
    }
}

public class Objet
{
    public List<crit> lstcrit
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class crit
{
    public string ValeurCrit
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```